# Организация процесса код ревью для небольшой команды с помощью Upsource

Tags: инспекция-кода

У [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) есть клевая система код ревью [Upsource](https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource).

В моей команде 3 человека. Хочу включить в наш рабочий процесс прохождение код ревью как обязательное требования вливания кода в ветку девелоп.

**Задача: все строчки кода вливаемые в ветку девелоп обязаны успешно пройти код ревью.**

Я хочу узнать у тех кто использует Upsource как и когда вы создаете код ревью. Его создает тот кто написал код? Как вы следите что изменения прошли код ревью? Какие соглашения с командой вы выработали по теме код ревью?

Пожалуйста, опишите ваш рабочий процесс с этой системой.

Comment: Поясните про соглашения. В такой формулировке этот вопрос тянет на отдельный топик.

Comment: @andreycha да, верно :) Не важно. Мне просто хотелось услышать примеры и получить легкий интрадакшен в тему. Вы отлично справились :)

Comment: Ну смотрите :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С Upsource я не работал, могу описать процесс на примере [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server) (недавно переименован в Bitbucker Server). Судя по тому, что я быстренько прочитал об Upsource, там есть [аналогичная функциональность](https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/whatsnew/#github-integration-pull-requests-and-more). Все описанное справедливо для использования git flow/github flow (судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам вы используете гит).

---

Разработчики работают в отдельных багфикс/фича бранчах. После завершения работы в Stash создается пулл-реквест, назначаются ревьюеры. В программе минимум -- это тим-лид, в программе максимум -- все члены команды.

При этом отдельно настраиваются критерии успешного код-ревью: сколько аппрувов нужно собрать. Например, если в ревьюеры назначается вся команда, можно сделать так, что для мержа достаточно аппрува двух участников. Это настройка относится к части администрирования и производится однократно.

Далее ревьюеры смотрят код, пишут комментарии. Комментарии могут быть как просто текстовыми, так и оформлены в виде задач. Текстовые комментарии никак не влияют на возможность мержа, т.е. приходится следить за ними глазами. С задачами чуть легче -- пока есть незакрытые задачи, Stash не даст замержить реквест.

После того, как набирается нужный кворум, реквест становится доступным для мержа. Но последнее слово за тим-лидом, поскольку обычно этот человек лучше всего знаком с архитектурой проекта: бывают ситуации, когда изменения валидны, ревью пройдено, но при этом с т.з. архитектуры проекта изменения не подходят. И вот тут пригождается "право вето". Правами на мерж, естественно, обладает только тим-лид. При этом Stash позволяет делать автоматический мерж после набора кворума (полезно, когда тим-лид в отпуске :)).

При этом отдельно в процесс ревью можно подключать статический анализатор кода. Все проблемы, найденные им, высвечиваются в реквесте и тоже должны быть исправлены. Однако на мой взгляд статический анализатор имеет смысл подключить уже на этапе билда. Есть ошибки -- нет билда.

---

Общие соображения на эту тему такие:

- у разработчиков не должно быть возможности влить свой код в условный
  мастер напрямую
- код вливается после соблюдения нескольких условий: зеленый билд,
  пройденное код-ревью, отсутствуют конфликты с мастером

---

Теперь конкретные ответы на вопросы.

> Его создает тот кто написал код?

Да.

> Как вы следите что изменения прошли код ревью?

Это могут быть как автоматические ограничения (на примере задач в Stash), так и дополнительный "ручной" контроль со стороны человека, который занимается мержем. Ну и дисциплина самих разработчиков: если Вася сообщил о проблеме в коде, он не должен тут же ставить аппрув.